# Water's ability to short an L18650 cell?

Tags: lithium-ion, short-circuit, water, risk-analysis, cell

Personally I no longer use 18650 cells, I use polymer packs with safety circuits.

However having once or twice in the past I have briefly shorted a connection between the positive terminal and the negative siding in the past, I'm curious:

Can water bridge the connection and cause a short?

When I have shorted and get a small spark (usually due to a small tear or hole in the plastic wrap) when the metal tab bridges the gap, I would always worry about the heat causing damage and possibly a fire.

How likely is this? And if water were to somehow breach the seal on a project is it possible for it to react the same way, ie a short with a spark and heat, presenting a possible fire hazard?

Comment: Yes, water can bridge the small space between positive and negative terminals on the 18650 cell.

Yes, the short caused by water has a chance of causing the battery to overheat and catch fire. It's not likely to spark.

Comment: Thank you for the relpy, do you know how this is prevent  in consumer electronics? I mean the cases on say a backup charger are usually pretty well sealed but how do they account for accident submersion?

Comment: Most consumer electronics is not rated for submersion. It's only in the last three to four years that smartphones have started to become rated for shallow water limited time submersion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [short circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_circuit) is an electrical circuit that allows a current to travel along an unintended path with **no or very low electrical impedance**.

Pure water has very high resistance. Dissolved impurities can lower the resistance dramatically, but not enough to 'short out' a 18650 cell to the point of creating dangerous current flow.

The main problem with water on a battery is electrolysis, which eats away wiring and causes a buildup of conductive sludge around exposed contacts. This could damage the cell connections and *eventually* cause it to over-discharge.

How long is 'eventually'? Recently I had to dispose of a 3S (11.1 V) 2200 mAh drone battery that had been in a crash. For safety I 'temporarily' stored it in a bucket of water. When I pulled it out 2 weeks later the plug was full of verdigris and all the balance wires had been eaten through, but it still had over 3.7 V per cell. Another 2 weeks in the bucket might have been enough to completely flatten it, but I discharged it through a 6 Ω resistor instead (which took about an hour).

Comment: Interesting... makes sense I guess as salt and such is often used to make water more conductive yeah?

Answer (score 1):

> Can water bridge the connection and cause a short?

It can bridge the connections, but if that causes a short depends on the relative resistance of the bridge compared to the internal resistance of the battery.  With relatively pure water, the resistance over the 65mm length of the cell will be enormous (many thousands of ohms).  Clearly this will not cause a short.  If dropped into salt water, the resistance will be much less, tens to hundreds of ohms.  However, the internal resistance of a 18650 cell is a tiny fraction of an ohm, so no, even very salty water is unlikely to cause a short unless the circuit brings the positive and negative supply lines *extremely* close together.

> And if water were to somehow breach the seal on a project is it possible for it to react the same way, ie a short with a spark and heat, presenting a possible fire hazard?

To cause a fire, you need to heat up the circuit enough that it combusts.  Bridging the wires of a circuit with water is unlikely to heat up the circuit much because most of the resistance is in the water, and so therefore most of the heating is in water too.  Since water cannot be raised above 100C, the maximum heating is limited.

Damage from water immersion is generally not thermal, but chemical.  Water is a great solvent, and when a voltage is formed across a volume of water, ions are stripped from the terminals of the circuit and dissolved into the water.  This corrodes the metal of the circuit, breaking contacts and destroying the device.

This video demonstrates the effect using cola (salt water essentially):  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FOgsjd5Uxt4